# Add table into existing PDF using iTExtsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have one PDF in that there is one table that table is dynamic and I want to add another table below to that table dynamically in my existing PDF.

Is there any way to add the table in existing PDF at specific place that existing table(that is not at the end of document) is completed then I want to add my table.

How can I add? Please suggest me some good way.

As you can see below image.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: You mention iTextSharp. That library allows the manipulation of existing pdfs using the PdfStamper class. More interesting is the question how to recognize the position in the existing PDF at which to add the new data.

Comment: Hi Mkl thanks for your comments. how can I recognize the position in the existing pdf so I can add the table. Can you give any example?

Comment: Can you give any example? No, because you're asking something that is impossible in many cases (not all). That's why mkl wrote the question on how to recognize the position in the existing PDF is a more interesting question. If you can't answer that question (because you're probably asking something that is impossible) your actual question is irrelevant. Nobody else can answer that question for you because nobody else knows what the existing PDF looks like.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I have added sample pdf image for the same. As you can see above image there "Items in your order" table that is dynamically, right now you can see four items there but it may very in different pdfs. I want to add table below to that table in existing pdf. Hope you this is help you to understand. Thanks,

Comment: It looks like it just might be possible in your case. If that *Thank you for your business...* line always is the first text after your table, one could use that and *Items in Your Order* to find the position. I just wonder what kind of table would fit into that small distance. I do hope you don't also expect the *Thank you...* line and anything below to be moved down, do you? While not impossible, that would make this a really big project.

Comment: Hi Mkl thanks for your reply. There will be a more space between that order table and Thank you... line but here I could not show you I just cut that space so you could not see.

Answer (score 3):

By far the easiest way to do this is to create a new PDF with the desired table at the desired location, then stamp it onto the existing PDF.  This can be done in code using (for example) the `PdfStamper` class, but there are also standalone tools such as `pdftk` and many others.  Don't think of this as "editing" a PDF, think of it as dropping something new on top of the original.

```
pdftk original.pdf stamp newtable.pdf output combined.pdf
```

The really interesting and potentially difficult part was addressed by @mkl's original question - how do you determine the correct position of the new table.  If you can come up with a geometric rule, then you are in good shape.  If this involves any parsing of the original file, you should be aware that something as (seemingly) simple as determining the number of rows in the existing table can sometimes be extremely difficult.  In all likelihood, there is noting like an html `<table>` tag buried in the content stream.  Having an example of an actual PDF would be very helpful.  An image of the PDF is not the same thing.

To give you some background information, parsing the *layout* of a PDF is easy, that's what PDF readers do.  Parsing the *content* of a PDF is completely different and much harder.  Just as an example, the PDF image you posted could be drawn from top to bottom, or the headers and footers could be drawn first followed by all the bold face items, followed by the plain faced text.  Just because two things are next to each other in the physical layout does not mean they are next to each other in the file structure, the object tree, or the content stream.  It's a vector graphic not a text file or a bitmap.  PDFs are not designed to be editable unless the software that creates it specifically provides clues as to how the content is to be edited.  There are a lot of things that seem like they *should* be easy, but once you understand how a PDF is built, it makes sense that it's difficult.  I'm not saying this to discourage you, just so that you appreciate the magnitude of the task.  If you can trace down the source document that this PDF was created from, I guarantee you will have more success with less frustration.

Answer (score 1):

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

/// Function which will create pdf document and save in the server folder

private void ExportDataToPDFTable()
    {
      Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
         try
          {
           string pdfFilePath = Server.MapPath(".") + "/pdf/myPdf.pdf";
           //Create Document class object and set its size to letter and give space left, right, Top, Bottom Margin
           PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdfFilePath, FileMode.Create));

           doc.Open();//Open Document to write

           Font font8 = FontFactory.GetFont("ARIAL", 7);

           //Write some content
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Using ITextsharp I am going to show how to create simple table in PDF document ");

            DataTable dt = GetDataTable();

            if (dt != null)
                {
                 //Craete instance of the pdf table and set the number of column in that table
                 PdfPTable PdfTable = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
                 PdfPCell PdfPCell = null;


                 //Add Header of the pdf table
                 PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("ID", font8)));
                 PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);

                 PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("Name", font8)));
                 PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);


                 //How add the data from datatable to pdf table
                 for (int rows = 0; rows < dt.Rows.Count; rows++)
                    {
                     for (int column = 0; column < dt.Columns.Count; column++)
                         {
                           PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dt.Rows[rows][column].ToString(), font8)));
                            PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);
                            }
                        }

                        PdfTable.SpacingBefore = 15f; // Give some space after the text or it may overlap the table

                        doc.Add(paragraph);// add paragraph to the document
                        doc.Add(PdfTable); // add pdf table to the document

                    }

                }
                catch (DocumentException docEx)
                {
                    //handle pdf document exception if any
                }
                catch (IOException ioEx)
                {
                    // handle IO exception
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // ahndle other exception if occurs
                }
                finally
                {
                    //Close document and writer
                    doc.Close();

       }
 }
```

Sample Datatable:

```
private DataTable GetDataTable()
    {
        // Create an object of DataTable class
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("MyDataTable");//Create ID DataColumn
        DataColumn dataColumn_ID = new DataColumn("ID", typeof(Int32));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn_ID);//Create another DataColumn Name
        DataColumn dataColumn_Name = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn_Name);
        //Now Add some row to newly created dataTable
        DataRow dataRow;for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            // Important you have create New row
            dataRow["ID"] = i;dataRow["Name"] = "Some Text " + i.ToString();
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        dataTable.AcceptChanges();
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Comment: Your code creates a new PDF while the original question asks for code to add to an existing one.